# Problem printing native pdf from electron project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, electron

I have an electron app as a desktop container for react project.
The functionality which i am seeking is receiving pdf file from ajax request and try to print it directly without showing any prompt.

I tried to pass the link of pdf file from UI to electron entrypoint using **contextBridge**

```
// open pdf method inside react page
const openPdfInNewWindow = (pdfLink) => {
    return new Promise(() => {
      window.electronAPI.openPdf(pdfLink, (response) => {
        console.log('Main: ', response);
      });
    });
  };
```

and here is the snippet of contextBrige in **preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
     contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
         openPdf: async (url, callback) => {
           const response = await ipcRenderer.invoke('openPdf', url);
           callback(response);
        },
     });
```

and here is the print functionality inside entypoint **main.ts**

```
ipcMain.handle('openPdf', async (event, pdfUrl) => {
  const newWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { plugins: false } });
 
  await newWindow.loadURL(pdfUrl);

  newWindow.webContents.on('did-frame-finish-load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      newWindow.webContents.print({silent: true});
    }, 3000);
  });

  return 'shown print dialog';
 
});
```

pdf file is showing successfully in new BrowserWindow but silent print showing empty pdf page